# How do switch cases work?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I got a switch case that is not registering anything despite meeting the proper conditions. How exactly do they work? here's the code

```
sClasificacionIMC = ''
    switch(nIMCDecimal){
        case 'Bajo peso':
            if(nIMCDecimal <18.50){
                sClasificacionIMC = 'Bajo peso'
            }
        break;
            case 'Delgadez severa':
                if(nIMCDecimal <16.00){
                    sClasificacionIMC = 'Delgadez severa'
            }
        break;
            case 'Delgadez moderada':
                if(nIMCDecimal > 16.00 && nIMCDecimal < 16.99){
                    sClasificacionIMC = 'Delgadez moderada'
                }
        break;
            case 'Delgadez leve':
                if(nIMCDecimal > 17.00 && nIMCDecimal < 18.49 ){
                    sClasificacionIMC = 'Delgadez leve'
                }
        break;
            case 'Normal':
                if(nIMCDecimal > 18.5 && nIMCDecimal < 24.99){
                    sClasificacionIMC = 'Normal'
                }
        break;
            case 'Sobrepeso':
                if(nIMCDecimal >= 25.00){
                    sClasificacionIMC = 'Sobrepeso'
                }
        break; 
            case'Preobeso':
                if(nIMCDecimal > 25.00 && nIMCDecimal < 29.99){
                    sClasificacionIMC = 'Preobeso'
                }
        break;
            case 'Obesidad':
                if(nIMCDecimal >= 30.00){
                    sClasificacionIMC = 'Obesidad'
                }
        break;
            case 'Obesidad leve':
                if(nIMCDecimal > 30.00 && nIMCDecimal < 34.99){
                    sClasificacionIMC = 'Obesidad leve'
                }
        break;
            case 'Obesidad media':
                if(nIMCDecimal > 35.00 && nIMCDecimal < 39.99){
                    sClasificacionIMC = 'Obesidad media'
                }
        break;
            case 'Obesidad morbida':
                if(nIMCDecimal >= 40.00){
                    sClasificacionIMC = 'Obesidad mórbida'
                }
        }
```

The results (sClasificacionIMC) is set to register into an array, but once registered, it just shows an empty field, it's not going for any of the cases despite meeting the criteria for it.

No console errors either.

I'm confused whether I should use nIMCDecimal on switch(nIMCDecimal) or if I should be using the sClasificacionIMC instead

Comment: What about that if conditions? It looks like nIMCDecimal is a numeric value, then how it can be something like string "Bajo peso"? Your switch statement seems to be wrong.

Comment: what is the purpose of ifs in the switch?

Comment: I thought it needed them to evaluate the range of the number im giving it?

Comment: You have to put your "test conditions" inside the cases. In `case 'Bajo peso':` you are expecting that the value passed to `nIMCDecimal` (variable name in the switch) is `Bajo peso`, that means that the code will only run into this case statement if `nIMCDecimal` variable is equal to `Bajo peso`.

Comment: You should NOT be using a switch statement here. You should just be using a bunch of `if(nIMCDecimal <16){} else if(nIMCDecimal <17) {} else if(nIMCDecimal <18) {} ....`

Comment: So can I set a range for a case condition? for example case 'nIMCDecimal > 18.5 && nIMCDecimal < 24.99':
     
                    sClasificacionIMC = 'Normal'

Comment: yeah, but the lesser number is sort of known if the previous if is at <18.49

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close! In this scenario (and others in the future like it), try not to use a switch statement. It is *much* easier to just use `if else` here. Here is your code using these!

```
const f = function(nIMCDecimal){
sClasificacionIMC = ''

  if(nIMCDecimal<18.50){
      sClasificacionIMC = 'Bajo peso'
  }else if(nIMCDecimal <16.00){
      sClasificacionIMC = 'Delgadez severa'

  }else if(nIMCDecimal > 16.00 && nIMCDecimal < 16.99){
      sClasificacionIMC = 'Delgadez moderada'

  }else if(nIMCDecimal > 17.00 && nIMCDecimal < 18.49){
      sClasificacionIMC = 'Delgadez leve'

  }else if(nIMCDecimal > 18.5 && nIMCDecimal < 24.99){
      sClasificacionIMC = 'Normal'

  }else if (nIMCDecimal >= 25.00){
      sClasificacionIMC = 'Sobrepeso'

  }else if(nIMCDecimal > 25.00 && nIMCDecimal < 29.99){
      sClasificacionIMC = 'Preobeso'

  }else if (nIMCDecimal >= 30.00){
      sClasificacionIMC = 'Obesidad'

  }else if (nIMCDecimal > 30.00 && nIMCDecimal < 34.99){
      sClasificacionIMC = 'Obesidad leve'

  }else if(nIMCDecimal > 35.00 && nIMCDecimal < 39.99){
      sClasificacionIMC = 'Obesidad media'

  }else if (nIMCDecimal >= 40.00){
      sClasificacionIMC = 'Obesidad mórbida'
  }
  return sClasificacionIMC 
}
console.log(f(2)) //Bajo peso
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) states:

> A switch statement first evaluates its expression.
>
> It then looks for the first case clause whose expression evaluates to the same value as the result of the input expression (using strict comparison, ===) and transfers control to that clause, executing the associated statements.
>
> (If multiple cases match the provided value, the first case that matches is selected, even if the cases are not equal to each other.)
>
> If no matching case clause is found, the program looks for the optional default clause, and if found, transfers control to that clause, executing the associated statements.
>
> If no default clause is found, the program continues execution at the statement following the end of switch. By convention, the default clause is the last clause, but it does not need to be so.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `switch` statement you should use the `if/else if` like shown below:

```
sClasificacionIMC = ''
if(nIMCDecimal <18.50){sClasificacionIMC = 'Bajo peso'}
else if(nIMCDecimal <16.00){ sClasificacionIMC = 'Delgadez severa'}
```

and so on. Hope this will help.